# How to target elements with a specific data attribute with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have several message boxes and each box has a data-author attribute.

If I want to apply styles to these message boxes in CSS, I can just do:

```
[data-author="Ben"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with Tailwind CSS or whether it's even possible. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 34):

As of Tailwind v3.2, data attribute variants are supported.

```html
<!-- Will apply -->
<div data-size="large" class="data-[size=large]:p-8">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>

<!-- Will not apply -->
<div data-size="medium" class="data-[size=large]:p-8">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

See here: https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-2#data-attribute-variants

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I was looking for! In my case, I needed to select the parent element's data attribute, but that can easily be achieved by using the `group` selector: `group-data[attr=value]:hidden`

Comment: Just to add to this, you don't have to have a value... could be `data-[touched]`

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by adding a variant. In your `tailwind.config.js`:

Add `const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')` at the top of the page.

Then in your export add:

```js
  plugins: [
    plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('ben', '&[data-author="Ben"]')
    }),
  ]
```

All you have to do is then use it how you want: `ben:bg-blue-500`

You would need to create a new one for each individual author though, or come up with a convention for grouping them by colors.

Comment: Thank you. It works and beautiful but I could not figure out why it does not work with `peer-ben:`?  Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to target not only data attributes, but any attribute and even use more complex CSS selectors with [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants). This allows for more flexibility than data attribute variants.

Examples:

```html
<div class="[&[data-author='Ben']]:bg-blue-300" data-author="Ben">Text</div>
<!-- select element based on value on data attribute -->

<div class="[&[data-flag]]:bg-blue-300" data-flag>Text</div>
<!-- select element based on presence of any attribute (not only data attributes) -->

<div class="enabled [&.enabled[data-flag]]:bg-blue-300" data-flag>Text</div>
<!-- select element based on both presence of enabled class and data-flag attribute -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the syntax you used above. for implementation problems, you can use the @apply directive which can directly call the utility class from tailwind

In addition, you can also apply a color that is outside the tailwind color by using an arbitrary value

```
[data-author="Ben"] {
  @apply bg-[#bada55];
}
```

You can learn more about arbitary value in this article:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with tailwind, you can only target elements by giving them classes. However, you can still write custom CSS and add styles to it with tailwind's `@apply`:

```css
[data-author="Ben"] {
  @apply bg-blue-500;
}
```